# Who introduced gravitational potential?

Tags: physics, gravity, potential, fluid-dynamics

Some sources say that gravitational potential was introduced by Lagrange in 1773, and others say that it was introduced by Bernoulli in 1738. I sifted through Daniel Bernoulli's *Hydrodynamica* (translation by Carmody and Kobus) but could not even find the mention of *velocity potential*, let alone a potential for Newtonian gravity. I am hoping somebody with more knowledge could clarify this for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The potential is not introduced in *Hydrodynamica*. Here is from [The Oxford Handbook of the History of Physics, p.366](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Oxford_Handbook_of_the_History_of_Ph/JWYBAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0):

> "*Gravitational potential appeared implicitly in the form of the integral of force in
> Johann Bernoulli’s formula for the motion of a point under the action of a central
> force (1712). Bernoulli did not connect his result with the conservation of vis viva;
> this step was taken in 1738 by his son Daniel, who also explicitly gave the form of
> the potential in the case of Newtonian attraction (1747). After an interval of more
> than twenty years, Lagrange began to make extensive use of the potential, at least as
> a formal mathematical entity in the equations of mechanics. He first applied it to
> the study of astronomical perturbations (1776), then to the general motion of masspoints
> subjected to mutual gravitational interactions (1779), and, finally, he inserted
> the potential in the equations of mechanics that bear his name (1782)*".

The 1712 reference is missing, and the 1738 reference is to *Commentationes de immutatione et extensione principii conservationisvirium
vivarum, quae pro motu corporum coelestium requiritur. Commentarii academiae scientiarum
Petropolitanae* 10 (1738), 116–124. [Here](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/113649#page/128/mode/1up) is a link.